# MongoDB 3.2 Java Driver: How To Use AggregateOperation

Tags: java, mongodb

I am interested in example code for using the MongoDB AggregateOperation driver to perform an $unwind activity. AggregateOperation seems to be associated with the MongoDB version 3+ Java driver.

Using AggregateOperation, how would I unwind the "sizes" array shown below?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56928aa190f425c1e987abc3d"), "item" : "Fleece-lined jeans", "sizes" : [ "30", "31", "38", "40", "42" ], "count" : 3 }
```

The aggregation examples I see on this forum seem mostly to use BasicDBObject objects and these apparently do not mix with the version 3 Java API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to invoke a static method `parse` inside the 
`import org.bson.Document;` class.

So, the below lines of code, should unwind the `sizes` array object for you in mongodb3.0 driver.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = client.getDatabase("test");
        MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase
                .getCollection("unwind");

        List<Document> pipeline;

        pipeline = Arrays.asList(Document.parse("{$unwind:\"$sizes\"}"));

        List<Document> results = mongoCollection.aggregate(pipeline).into(
                new ArrayList<Document>());

        for (Document cur : results) {
            System.out.println(cur.toJson());
        }
```

For 3.2 java driver.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.unwind;

Bson unwind = unwind("$sizes");

        List<Bson> pipeline = asList(unwind);

        MongoClient c = new MongoClient();
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = c.getDatabase("test")
                .getCollection("unwind");

        List<Document> results = collection.aggregate(pipeline).into(
                new ArrayList<Document>());

        for (Document cur : results) {
            System.out.println(cur.toJson());
        }
    }
```

Here `test` is the database and `unwind` is the collection.
This unwinds the sizes array object and below are the output documents.

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5692fed991b81360d23f1b54" }, "item" : "Fleece-lined jeans", "sizes" : "30", "count" : 3.0 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5692fed991b81360d23f1b54" }, "item" : "Fleece-lined jeans", "sizes" : "31", "count" : 3.0 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5692fed991b81360d23f1b54" }, "item" : "Fleece-lined jeans", "sizes" : "38", "count" : 3.0 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5692fed991b81360d23f1b54" }, "item" : "Fleece-lined jeans", "sizes" : "40", "count" : 3.0 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5692fed991b81360d23f1b54" }, "item" : "Fleece-lined jeans", "sizes" : "42", "count" : 3.0 }
```

Above code didn't use DBObject class which is deprecated in 3.0 version of MongoDB java driver.

Have tested the 3.0 version of code in 3.2 version of mongodb driver and it produced the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code example! I will try this out soon. I should have mentioned in my original post that I am using MongoDB version 3.2.0 and the Java driver 3.2.0 as well.

Comment: have added the code for 3.2 version of mongodb java driver.

Comment: When I tried to code `Bson unwind = unwind("$sizes");` for the 3.2 driver example you give, IntelliJ IDEA kept indicating this was an error. Perhaps because I had not imported the right methods. So I tried the solution shown below which works for me. It is based on [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/aggregation/) . I will try your 3.0 example as well.

Comment: There seems to be a few different ways to do $unwind in Java.

Comment: Your 3.0 solution works for me inside the 3.2.0 driver also, I did have to cast like so:   <br>`List<Document> results = (List<Document>) collection.aggregate(pipeline).into(new ArrayList<Document>());`

Comment: For 3.2 driver,  you have to import static methods of unwind present in Aggregates class

Comment: Hi, now I added the class to be loaded for unwind. It shouldn't show any errors in the IDE.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a try soon. I really appreciate your help since I am pretty new to both Java and MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution. It is based on [This documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/aggregation/%22This%20MongoDB%20document%22)

```
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("inventory").aggregate(asList(
            new Document("$unwind", "$sizes")
            ));

    iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        public void apply(Document document) {
            System.out.println(document.toJson());
        }
    });
```